# Using AJAX in Symfony

Tags: php, html, ajax, symfony, twig

I am trying to use "typeahead" function with Symfony. But my AJax code seem not to be working. Can you guys point me out to the fault?I searched in the internet many times and all most all the questions asked regarding this has not being answered well. Please if someone can arrange these to work in symfony 2.8, it will be a great help to lot of people.Thank you

My Twig code

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $('#country').typeahead({
  source: function(query, result)
  {
   $.ajax({
    url:"{{path('fetch')}}",
    method:"POST",
    data:{query:query},
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(data)
    {
     result($.map(data, function(item){
      return item;
     }));
    }
   })
  }
 });
 
});
</script>
```

```html
<input type="text" name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Type Country Name" />
```

My controller

```
/**
 * @Route("/fetch", name="fetch")
 */
public function preAllAction(Request $request)
{

    //fetch.php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "galleit");
    $request = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE name LIKE '%".$request."%'";

    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    $data = array();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data[] = $row["name"];
        }
        echo json_encode($data);
    }

}
```

Comment: You said "But my AJax code seem not to be working." Can you please elaborate with some sort of error you get?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your `Symfony` controller returns a response (any type it is)?
You should replace `echo json_encode($data)` by `return new JsonResponse($data)`

---

*Make sure the `JsonResponse` class has been loaded by your controller.*

Comment: This really seems more like a question than an answer.  Good way to get yourself down voted.  The question does not contain nearly enough information to answer.

Comment: I'm telling it because the controller generally end by returning a response not with echo function.